# Slack: How to set default/selected value on interactive menu

Tags: slack, slack-api

I have slack interactive menu, which is working fine apart from the fact, that I want to have the currently selected value, shown in the menu. After reading the docs, I figured the attachment should look something like this:

```
{
    'text': 'settings.slack_notification_time ',
    'fallback': 'oops',
    'color': '#3AA3E3',
    'attachment_type': 'default',
    'callback_id': callback_id,
    'actions': [
        {
            'name': 'notification_time',
            'text': 'Choose a notification_time',
            'type': 'select',
            'selected_options': [
                {
                    'text': '07:00',
                    'value': 7
                }
            ],
            'options': [
                {text:'01:00',value:1},
                {text:'02:00',value:2},
                {text:'03:00',value:3},
                ....

            ]                       
        }
    ]
};
```

What is the correct way of setting the selected options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the issue. Slack can apparently only compare string option.value.
Forcing the values on both the options list and the select_options, to be strings, made it work.

Comment: can you post your final object? I am facing the same issue and not able to figure out how to pass a string to selected_options.

Comment: we can simply use "value":"7"  in recent versions.

Answer (score 5):

"initial_option" works for me.

FYI.
[Sample](https://app.slack.com/block-kit-builder/T47435J48#%7B%22blocks%22:%5B%7B%22type%22:%22section%22,%22text%22:%7B%22type%22:%22mrkdwn%22,%22text%22:%22Pick%20an%20item%20from%20the%20dropdown%20list%22%7D,%22accessory%22:%7B%22type%22:%22static_select%22,%22placeholder%22:%7B%22type%22:%22plain_text%22,%22text%22:%22Select%20an%20item%22,%22emoji%22:true%7D,%22initial_option%22:%7B%22text%22:%7B%22type%22:%22plain_text%22,%22text%22:%22*this%20is%20plain_text%20text*%22,%22emoji%22:true%7D,%22value%22:%22value-1%22%7D,%22options%22:%5B%7B%22text%22:%7B%22type%22:%22plain_text%22,%22text%22:%22*this%20is%20plain_text%20text*%22,%22emoji%22:true%7D,%22value%22:%22value-0%22%7D,%7B%22text%22:%7B%22type%22:%22plain_text%22,%22text%22:%22*this%20is%20plain_text%20text*%22,%22emoji%22:true%7D,%22value%22:%22value-1%22%7D,%7B%22text%22:%7B%22type%22:%22plain_text%22,%22text%22:%22*this%20is%20plain_text%20text*%22,%22emoji%22:true%7D,%22value%22:%22value-2%22%7D%5D,%22action_id%22:%22static_select-action%22%7D%7D%5D%7D)

code:

```
{
"blocks": [
    {
        "type": "section",
        "text": {
            "type": "mrkdwn",
            "text": "Pick an item from the dropdown list"
        },
        "accessory": {
            "type": "static_select",
            "placeholder": {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "Select an item",
                "emoji": true
            },
            "initial_option": {
                "text": {
                    "type": "plain_text",
                    "text": "*this is plain_text text*",
                    "emoji": true
                },
                "value": "value-1"
            },
            "options": [
                {
                    "text": {
                        "type": "plain_text",
                        "text": "*this is plain_text text*",
                        "emoji": true
                    },
                    "value": "value-0"
                },
                {
                    "text": {
                        "type": "plain_text",
                        "text": "*this is plain_text text*",
                        "emoji": true
                    },
                    "value": "value-1"
                },
                {
                    "text": {
                        "type": "plain_text",
                        "text": "*this is plain_text text*",
                        "emoji": true
                    },
                    "value": "value-2"
                }
            ],
            "action_id": "static_select-action"
        }
    }
]
```

}